# 'int' Object not Callable

Tags: python, int, callable

Im making a simple python script to process a table. I am using a array to store the cell values.
Heres the code:

```
table =[]
hlen = input("Please enter the amount of columns \n")
vlen = input("Please enter the amount of rows \n")
curcol = 1
currow = 1
totcell = hlen*vlen
while (totcell >= curcol * currow):
   str = input("Please input "+ str(curcol) +"," + str(currow))
   table.append(str)
   if (curcol >= hlen):
       currow =+ 1

//Process Table
```

The program runs sweet, asking for the first cell at 1,1. All is well, until the code stops when reloading. Heres pythons error output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Evacuation.py", line 13, in <module>
    str = input("Please input "+ str(curcol) +"," + str(currow))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: dont name your variables `str`(or `input`) and your problem is solved ...

Comment: `currow =+ 1` → `currow += 1`?

Comment: Use `pylint`. It will pickup common problems  like this.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, as you probably have guessed, I am rather new to python :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're shadowing the built in `str` with your variable name:

```
str = input("Please input "+ str(curcol) +"," + str(currow))
```

The second time around, with `str(currow)` you're trying to *call* `str`, which is now an `int`

Name it **anything but that!**

Also, you're in Python 2, so it's far preferred to use `raw_input` instead of `input`

Answer (score 1):

```
  m = input("Please input "+ str(curcol) +"," + str(currow))
  please use different name of variable not use 'str' because it is python default function for type  casting

  table =[]
  hlen = input("Please enter the amount of columns \n")
  vlen = input("Please enter the amount of rows \n")
  curcol = 1
  currow = 1
  totcell = hlen*vlen
  while (totcell >= curcol * currow):
       m = input("Please input "+ str(curcol) +"," + str(currow))
  table.append(m)
  if (curcol >= hlen):
    currow += 1



   Please enter the amount of columns 
   5
  Please enter the amount of rows 
   1
  Please input 1,11
  Please input 1,11
  Please input 1,1
  >>> ================================ RESTART ================================
  >>> 
  >>>Please enter the amount of columns 
  >>>1
  Please enter the amount of rows 
  1
 Please input 1,12


 see this program and run it .
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `str` as a variable name for the `int` you are returning from the input. Python is referring to that when you use str(curcol) and str(currow), rather than the Python string function.